# Angular directive bind to factory

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing an Angular-based admin dashboard using sbAdmin template (with sbAdmin-angular template I've found)...

The issue is that I have a Factory where I fetch the data from the server, the controllers can ask for the data (the fetched in the last update) or ask the factory for update them:

```
app.factory("appData", function($http, $q) {
    var data = null;

    var getData = function() {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        var promise = defered.promise;
        if (!data) {
            console.log("Fetching data")
            updateData().then(function(data) {
                defered.resolve(data);
            });
        } else {
            defered.resolve(data);
        }
        return promise;
    }

    var updateData = function() {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        var promise = defered.promise;

        $http.get('/appData').success(function(response) {
            //Retrieve the data
            data = response;
            defered.resolve(data);
        })});
        return promise;
    }

    return {
        getData: getData,
        updateData: updateData
    };
})
```

When I update the data, the controllers that each state use, the bind works well. But I have a sidebar implemented using a directive:

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp')
    .directive('sidebar', ['$location', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/sidebar/sidebar.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {},
            controller: function($scope, appData) {
                ... bla, bla, bla...

                appData.getData().then(function(data) {
                    $scope.appData = data;
                })

                ... bla, bla, bla...
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Anyone knows why here in the directive, the factory (singleton) data is not update like in the controllers?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1):

Note that in `updateData()` if you get an error return from the request your promise will neither resolve nor reject. My guess would be you get an error and as you aren't handling it the request never completes.

Make sure that `updateData` either resolves or rejects. Also it can be made a lot simpler by just returning the promise you have instead of creating a new one. Don't use the deprecated `success` method, just treat the result as an ordinary promise (there is a slight difference with `then` you have to extract the `response.data` yourself while `success` splits the response into separate parameters):

```
var updateData = function() {
    return $http.get('/appData').then(function(response) {
        //Retrieve the data
        data = response.data;
        return data;
    });
}
```

`getdata` can also be simplified similarly:

```
var getData = function() {
    if (!data) {
        console.log("Fetching data")
        return updateData();
    } else {
        return $q.resolve(data);
    }
}
```

Now any error from the `$http` call will bubble all the way back to your directive and you can handle it there.

Comment: it does... but i delete it in order to reduce the code...

.error(function(response) {
            console.log("Error getting the data from the server!");
            defered.reject(response);
            console.log(response)
        });

Comment: in that case my guess is that the problem is in some other bit of code you deleted.